# Woocommerce complete order and add info to email programmatically

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to make an order `Completed` manually and add tracking info to the email before it has been sent to the customer. I added a note to the order successfully but note is not in the email. How I can add the tracking code to the email?

Here is my code:

```
if(!empty(wc_get_order($ord->orderId))){
    $order = wc_get_order($ord->orderId);

    if($ord->statusId == 2){ //completed
        $order->add_order_note( 'Tracking Number:'.$ord->trackingNumber );
        $order->update_status( 'completed', $ord->trackingNumber );
    }
    else if($ord->statusId == 3){
        $order->update_status( 'cancelled' );
    }
    var_dump($order);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override emails default HTML template by copying `/woocommerce/templates/` [+any file you would like to override] to your theme/child theme folder. If you never overrode any woocommerce template in your theme - [go here](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#how-to-edit-files).

The html generated for the `completed` email is `emails/customer-completed-order.php` file, add your code to include the tracking number or any text you would like.

EDIT: To trigger your function when you change order status from processing to completed is the following `add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_function_name', 10, 1);`

Comment: The problem is that I want to do it in a function, inside the code snippet I posted above

Comment: I wont question where you grab "$ord->trackingNumber" as this implifies you got it covered.

If you want to trigger a function after you change the order from processing to completed, then use woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_completed action to trigger your function, i.e. add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_function_name', 10, 1);

Comment: yes $ord is coming from webservice. My function calls update_status to set the status. ok maybe i will set tracking to a meta and then alter the email template to read that meta